# Laravel 8 error vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, mbstring

i want to ask about the problem i'm having. I'm using 2 desktops i.e. ubuntu and mint, when I run my code on ubuntu it runs smoothly. but if i run on mint desktop i have an error that says "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

and i get this log on my terminal

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Tue Nov  9 16:18:53 2021] PHP 8.0.12 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Tue Nov  9 16:18:55 2021] 127.0.0.1:38908 Accepted
[Tue Nov  9 16:18:55 2021] 127.0.0.1:38910 Accepted
[Tue Nov  9 16:20:22 2021] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in /home/aditya/Documents/Laravel/eyrin/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php on line 632
[Tue Nov  9 16:20:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:38908 Closing
[Tue Nov  9 16:20:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:38910 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Tue Nov  9 16:20:23 2021] 127.0.0.1:38910 Closing
```

and this is code on controller

```
        $store = Store::where('user_id',Helper::getSession('user_id'))->first();
        
        $match_report = [];
        $top_weekly_product = [];

        $compressed_date = [];
        $uncompressed_date = Report::where('store_id',$store->id)->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->select('created_at')->distinct()->get();
        foreach ($uncompressed_date as $item) {
            if(!in_array(Carbon::parse($item['created_at'])->format('d/m/Y'),$match_report)){
                $match_report[] = Carbon::parse($item['created_at'])->format('d/m/Y');
                $compressed_date[] = $item;
            }
        }

        $match_report = [];

        $compressed_weekly_product = [];
        $uncompressed_weekly_product = Report::where('store_id',$store->id)->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get()->map(function($report){
            return [
                'product_name'=>$report->product_name,
                'product_variant'=>$report->product_variant,
                'product_sku'=>$report->product_sku,
                'weekly_amount'=>sizeof(Report::where(['store_id'=>$report->store_id, 'product_sku'=>$report->product_sku])->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get())
            ];
        });

        foreach ($uncompressed_weekly_product as $item) {
            if(!in_array($item['product_sku'],$match_report)){
                $match_report[] = $item['product_sku'];
                $compressed_weekly_product[] = $item;
            }
        }

        foreach ($compressed_weekly_product as $key => $item) {
            $rows = [];
            foreach ($compressed_date as $obj) {
                $rows[] = sizeof(Report::where(['store_id'=>$store->id, 'product_sku'=>$item['product_sku']])->whereDate('created_at', Carbon::parse($obj['created_at']))->get());
            }
            $compressed_weekly_product[$key]['daily_amount'] = $rows;
        }

        foreach ($compressed_date as $key => $item) {
            $compressed_date[$key]['formated'] = Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('m/d/Y');
        }

        $match_report = [];

        usort($compressed_weekly_product, function($a, $b) { 
            return $a['weekly_amount'] > $b['weekly_amount'] ? -1 : 1;
        }); 

        foreach ($compressed_weekly_product as $item) {
            if(sizeof($top_weekly_product) < 3){
                $top_weekly_product[] = $item;
            }
        }

        //testing
        $growth_percentage = 1.8;

        return view('panel.outlet.dashboard.index', [
            'is_dashboard'=>true,
            'total_customer'=>sizeof(Customer::where('store_id',$store->id)->get()),
            'total_revenue'=>Order::where('store_id',$store->id)->whereIn('status',['2','3','-'])->sum('total_amount'),
            'total_order'=>sizeof(Order::where('store_id',$store->id)->get()),
            'total_sales'=>sizeof(Order::where('store_id',$store->id)->whereIn('status',['2','3','-'])->get()),
            'total_product'=>sizeof(Product::where('store_id',$store->id)->get()),
            'total_sales_income'=>Order::where('store_id',$store->id)->whereIn('status',['2','3','-'])->sum('total_amount'),
            'growth_percentage'=>round($growth_percentage,2),
            'lastest_order'=>Order::where(['store_id'=>$store->id,'type'=>'app'])->orderBy('id','DESC')->limit(10)->get(),
            'report_date'=>$compressed_date,
            'top_weekly_product'=>$top_weekly_product,
            'weekly_product'=>$compressed_weekly_product,
            'weekly_report'=>DailyReport::where('store_id',$store->id)->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get()]);
    }
```

can anyone help me with this problem? i had a similar experience when i tried to truncrate a string in my blade view. does it have something to do with the configuration in my php.ini?

thankss i hope get solution for this problem...

Answer (score 1):

Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

There was a problem with the route. check your web.php
Route::get('feedback', 'App\Http\Controllers\FeedBackController@index')->name('feedback.index');

changed to

Route::get('cfeedback', 'App\Http\Controllers\FeedBackController@index')->name('feedback.index');

added only c in before feedback

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

Running php via software collection the mbstring package was not installed.

```
# dnf install -y php73-php-mbstring
# systemctl restart php73-php-fpm
```

After installing packages and restarting service it was working well.

Comment: This has fixed it for me, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error appends when the `max_execution_time` of your PHP is reached. From the look of your error, it is probably set to 60 seconds.

You can increase this limit directly into your php.ini file (see with the command php --ini where it is located on your machine) or try to optimize your code.

If you don't want to edit the max_execution_time permanently, you can also add the instruction:

```
set_time_limit($seconds);
```

at the beginning of your script. I would not recommend this solution.

Comment: i have do this by increase max_execution_time, but still not works:", and solved if i have reinstall my php

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the php.ini file in the `max_execution_time` variable, the default is 60 seconds, you can change it according to your needs

Comment: i have change this value, but still not work, i think this problem on my php.ini. because i have reinstall my php / my xampp and now this problem has solved

Answer (score 0):

In your php.ini file, Uncomment `extension=mbstring` and you will see the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from checking the spelling of your route also check if there are duplicate route name in your web.php.  If there are then rename one of them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).